# JQUERY hover() function not applying to its children, using bootstrap framework

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right, when I hover over the class .col-lg-6 I want the div with class of .navText to hide.

HTML:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <a class="homeNav col-lg-12" href="index.html">
                    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-home pull-left"></div>
                    <div class="navText">Home</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <a class="aboutNav col-lg-12" href="about.html">
                    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-home pull-left"></div>
                    <div class="navText">About Me</div>
                </a>
            </div>               
        </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
        $('.col-lg-6').hover(function () {
            $(this).children('.navText').hide();
        });
```

This isn't working. 
However if I just put:

```
        $('.navText').hide();
```

It does work so why isn't my hover function working correctly. I'm a little confused as I'm 100% sure I have written to jquery correct. Could bootstrap be effecting this?

Also if I use the jquery code.

```
$('.col-lg-6').hover(function () {
    $('.navText').hide();
});
```

It will hide all the .navText classes.

So its having a problem with $(this) I think

Answer (score 3):

`.navText` is not a child of `.col-lg-6`. It is a child of it's child. So your jQuery function would not work. Why not use css here?

```
.col-lg-6:hover .navText {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very silly of me. I can tell ive been developing to much today making school boy errors like this haha

Comment: No worries. It happens to everyone. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As KJ has pointed out `.navText` is not a child, css is the best approach however you can also use `.find()` which will traverse all lower elements.

```
$(this).find('.navText').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

.navText is not a direct child of .col-lg-6. Use `find` instead:

```
$('.col-lg-6').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.navText').hide();
});
```